# Is it correct to say "with less"?

Tags: comparative

When I want to refer to something (which has the least amount of something), is it correct to say "with less"? For example:

> The house *with less* windows in the town.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as if you mean "The house with fewest windows in the town".

There are two issues:

1. There is a rule against using "less" for countable objects like windows: you're supposed to use "fewer". This is a totally arbitrary and unnecessary rule, that was only invented a couple of centuries ago, and is often disregarded; but some people will judge you unmercifully for not following it.
2. You are talking about the single most extreme example, rather than just making a comparison, so you need the superlative ("least", or "fewest") rather than the comparative ("less" or "fewer").

Answer (score 3):

No, ***less* is a comparative**.

You would need to say *the house with least windows in the town*.

However, as *window* happens to be a countable noun, (and not a mass-noun), it would be slightly better to say ***the house with fewest windows in the town***.

But you could say *the beach with the least sand in the south of England is at Brighton*.

If you were just comparing two things, it would be *the house with fewer windows*, and *the beach with less sand*.